# Feed Me accessing resource

Tags: plugin-feedme

Got a Feed Me feed set up to scrape a CSV that is being added to the server via FTP daily. The FTP is via a separate user account and the folder the file is being saved to is accessed via a symlink on the server.

The file is set in Feed Me as a relative path: `../resources/file.csv`

We set up a CRON job to hit the Feedme endpoint on an hourly basis but it is throwing an  error:

```
Unable to reach ../resources/file.csv. Message: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host each time
```

However I can access the element map just fine via the CP (showing it can read/access the file) and if I trigger the feed via the CP then it works okay.

Any thoughts on why triggering via a CRON/Direct Feed URL would not work but via the CP is fine?

Cole

Comment: Where is this folder, relative to your project's root (where your `craft` executable is)?

Comment: @Oli the folder is in the same application folder as the craft executable. However the file it is reading is being written to by another (FTP) user although the both users belong to the same group on the server

Answer (score 1):

You can use Yii aliases in the feed URL setting.

In the example below, I used the `@storage` alias which resolves to `/var/www/html/craft/storage` on my server, and then added the path to my file, relative to the Craft storage folder. As a result, the feed URL is the absolute path: `/var/www/html/craft/storage/import/business-units.csv`.

You can use any of the aliases listed on the `/admin/utilities/system-report` page.

Example: `@root/../resources/file.csv`, if your CSV is located in  the parent directory of your Craft directory.

[image: Screenshot of the settings page of a FeedMe feed]

Comment: Thanks @nstCactus - will try with an alias and see if that works but it really does seem quite random. For example having set to run hourly have had two instances in the last 24 hours where it has worked fine and the remaining 22 have reported being unable to reach the specified file